# How to get accuracy/confidence in places autocomplete service search for automated validation?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In a situation where a non-validated address string is provided, I need to programmatically make sure that an address exists and is plausible before continuing. In this process, no user- or manual interaction is allowed to take place.

The address string can range from very accurate e.g. `"street housenumber, zipcode city country"` to something very inaccurate like this `"housenumber, country"`.

Assuming our search term is `"main 1"`
Using the places autocomplete service, I receive a long list of possible matches, but they are not very accurate thus no validation should take place.

Assuming our search term is `"1 Main Street, Brooklyn, NY, USA"`
I might get a list with multiple addresses:

```
* 1 Main Street, Brooklyn, NY, USA
* 10 Main Street, Brooklyn, NY, USA
* 11 Main Street, Brooklyn, NY, USA
* ...
```

The first match in the list is a high accuracy match compared to the first example and can be used as a solid match.

So is there any way to tell the result quality apart in a technical manner?

Comment: Tell the accuracy? Base on what? What is your frame of reference? What's the expected output? An accuracy score? Valid/Invalid? Your question is **too broad** and your goal is unclear. Kindly reformat your question so that it can be answered. Also have you explored the various Google APIs and know what you will be using? Asking for API recommendations is off-topic on Stack overflow. You must do your own research.

Comment: @MrUpsidown thank you, tried to improve. Is there any other way to be more specific?

Comment: Is this supposed to happen on user input? Or are you trying to somehow *misuse* the service? Your use case is still unclear.

Comment: @MrUpsidown as stated in the first two sentences: In a situation where a non-validated address string is provided, I need to programmatically make sure that an address exists and is plausible before continuing. In this process, no user- or manual interaction is allowed to take place.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. You are talking about the validation, I am talking about the input. What/who would *type* or *enter* a string in the autocomplete field? If you would provide a [mcve], that would probably help.

Comment: I've the same use case. @Theo have you found a solution?

Comment: @AndreaSalicetti unfortunately no real solution to my problem yet.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are building a programmatic service that does not involve user interaction, your use case seems better suited to use Geocoding API instead of Place Autocomplete. Place Autocomplete is intended to provide typeahead predictions based on user input, whereas Geocoding API takes an "address" as input and returns its best match(es) for that input including full address information and lat/lng coordinates.

Geocoding API request documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview#GeocodingRequests

If you're using Maps JS API, Geocoding service documentation:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding